# dlib 19.6 multi classifier training data

Tags: c++, tensorflow, computer-vision, dlib

I'm working on object detection using **dlib 19.6** c++, till now i was using single classification like below
[image]
 , these labels are generated using imglab from dlib.

For this I'm using [fhog_object_detector_ex.cpp](http://dlib.net/fhog_object_detector_ex.cpp.html). It works well and able to detect object.

Now I have defined multi classifier like below. 
[image]
 1. clock
 2. pot

so how can i use/modify [fhog_object_detector_ex.cpp](http://dlib.net/fhog_object_detector_ex.cpp.html) to train data. I have knowledge on how to test image,

```
std::vector<object_detector<image_scanner_type> > my_detectors;
        my_detectors.push_back(detector1); // clock.svm
        my_detectors.push_back(detector2); // pot.svm
        my_detectors.push_back(detector3); // any other.svm
```

std::vector dets2 = evaluate_detectors(my_detectors, image);

but i'm not sure how can i train data. do i need to label 2 times separately for each image and run object trainer 2 times? or it is possible to train 2 classifiers same time?

Comment: It seems multi classifier is not available in dlib or no one worked, do I need to look into tensor flow for this? So dlib only works on Single classifier.

Comment: tensorflow does multi classification, or what you're really describing here is object detection, quite well. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection

Answer (score 0):

Dlib HOG detector doesn't support multiclass classifier.SO you need to train two separate detectors for each label and then combine detectors to run on a single image based on weight index you get the label of the detector.